# Cryptocurrency Exchange: Does coinbase charge you for gas fees?

Tags: cryptocurrency

I'm reading this [article](https://blog.shrimpy.io/blog/coinbase-vs-uniswap) which says coinbase could charge you for gas fees.

> However, when Ethereum gets congested, Coinbase will charge you for
> gas fees too. When it comes to gas, Uniswap and Coinbase are a wash.

Is this actually true?  I was under the impression that coinbase only charged you market fees, like any other centralized exchange.

The [fee page](https://help.coinbase.com/en/pro/trading-and-funding/trading-rules-and-fees/fees) on coinbase makes no mention of gas fees.

Comment: Any technical crypto question should go on the Crypto SE; questions which relate to the personal finance implications of cryptocurrency can go on money.SE.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon crypto != cryptocurrency. I will edit the title, but it should have been pretty clear anyway that the question relates to finance.

Comment: for clarity, I mean the crypto currency SE, whatever it is called. I think just bitcoin.SE, but technically it is more broad than that I believe.